# Configuring live-boot and live-config on debian

Tags: debian, livecd, debian-cd

I'm trying to build a custom debian live CD using [Will Haley's article](https://willhaley.com/blog/custom-debian-live-environment/) with `xfce4` and `lightdm` as a graphical desktop environment and `calamares` as a default installer but i can't set the live CD auto login for my live user because the system is booting to lightdm login window and asking for username and password, so how can I use the `live-config` package to configuring live CD to set and use a custom username and password ?

Comment: Have you configured the autologin settings in the lightdm configuration file of your Live boot environment?

Answer (score 0):

you just need modify your config file in the mastering-isodir

```
$ cat /etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf

[Seat:*] 
autologin-guest=false    
autologin-user="put here your live user name"    
autologin-user-timeout=0
```